# Building regex for address validation

Tags: regex, bash

I am trying to build a regex that fulfills these requirements

**Number Street Name**

*Number - at least one digit, followed by an arbitrary number of additional digits
Street Name - An arbitrary number of words (at least one) each beginning with a capital letter or number, followed by any number of lower and upper case letters, numbers, or periods (.).*

Examples of valid strings are

"123 Milk Ln."

"15090 178th Ave"

"27 Hilltop Dr. Apt. 7"

Examples of invalid strings are

"F52 Milk Ln."

"156A Fantastic St."

"56 sample Ln."

"1838 Dykhouse Ave. "

```
                 ^ extra space on the end
```

"1832 7th st."

Any help with the regex would be appreciated

> I have tried the following :

```
[A-Z][a-z]+,\s[A-Z][a-z]+[^\s](\s[A-Z].)
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: [A-Z][a-z]+,\s[A-Z][a-z]+[^\s](\s[A-Z].)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try that:

```
^\d\d*(\s(?:[A-Z0-9][A-Za-z0-9.]*)){1,}$
```

Explanation:

1. `^` start of line
2. \d\d* one digit followed by optional zero or more digits
3. `\s(?:[A-Z0-9][A-Za-z0-9.]*)` means space followed by Capital letter
   or number atleast one, followed by A-Za-z0-9. zero or more time(*)
   the above sequence must occur 1 or more time {1,}
4. $ end of string

[Regex 101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/r12uPg/1/)

Comment: @arashid I have added the explanation, let me know if anything is unclear... ps the \d\d* is equivalant to \d+ you may replace that as well

Comment: I got this one, but i have an error with another one also.

Comment: @PJProudhon yes that's for sure... but the elaborated {1,} lets new regex user to understand if he may need it two times or more than he may just replace the 1 by 2

Comment: Here is the shorter version of the regex in the answer: `^\d+( [A-Z\d][A-Za-z\d.]*)+$`. The only change I made was changing the `\s` to a regular space, since `\s` matches all whitespace characters, including the tab and newline character.

Comment: This is not working in BASH can you give me one that will work in BASH?

Answer (score 0):

```
^\d+ [\dA-Z](?: *[\da-zA-Z.])+$
```

- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `[\dA-Z]` - digit or a capital letter
- `(?: *` - non-capturing group, with zero or more spaces
- `[\da-zA-Z.]` - digit, capital letter, or small letter
- `)+` - end of the non-capturing group. The group should appear 1 or more times

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QfpLxS/1)

Comment: This is not working in BASH can you give me one that will work in BASH?